# Stripe saying 'Payment not completed' Stripe connect php

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment

When transferring money to a connected account on Stripe using this code

```
// // Create a PaymentIntent:
$method = \Stripe\PaymentMethod::create([
  'type' => 'card',
  'card' => [
    'number' => '4242424242424242',
    'exp_month' => 12,
    'exp_year' => 2020,
    'cvc' => '314',
  ],
]);


$paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
'amount' => $AMOUNT1,
'currency' => 'nzd',
'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
'payment_method' => $method->id,  
'customer' => CUSTOMER_ID,
'transfer_group' => '{ORDER'.$_SESSION['order_id'].'}',
]);

// Create a Transfer to a connected account (later):
$transfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create([
'amount' => $AMOUNT2,
'currency' => 'nzd',
'destination' => $ACC_ID,
'transfer_group' => '{ORDER'.$_SESSION['order_id'].'}',
]);
```

The payment stores on the connected account's dashboard and says its completed but when it stores on my **Payments** tab it says that the payment is incomplete and that the buyer has not completed the payment

[Prev1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5LFN.png)
[Prev2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7hOY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to confirm the payment intent, either by providing `confirm=true` at creation or by making a call to `/confirm`.

You're creating a transfer from your account to the connected one, which succeeds, and a payment that you never complete.